# Using a double for loop for a 2D array causing ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making a program that calculates the distance a projectile will travel. It is given two arrays, one of the possible projectile launch speeds, one of the possible projectile launch angles. It's supposed to loop through them one at a time, and add the output to a 2D array to be printed in a graph later on.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myLaunchSpeeds.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < myLaunchAngles.length; i++) {

            myLaunchAngles[j] = Math.toRadians(myLaunchAngles[j]);

            myDistances[i][j] = myLaunchSpeeds[i] * Math.sin((2 * myLaunchAngles[j])); //this is where the error is
            myDistances[i][j] = myDistances[i][j] / 9.8;

        }
```

However, when I run it, I get an array index out of bounds error. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're incrementing `i` in your `j` for loop.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < myLaunchAngles.length; i++) {`

replace i++ with j++ :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop has `++i` where it should have `++j`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myLaunchSpeeds.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < myLaunchAngles.length; i++) {

            myLaunchAngles[j] = Math.toRadians(myLaunchAngles[j]);

            myDistances[i][j] = myLaunchSpeeds[i] * Math.sin((2 * myLaunchAngles[j])); //this is where the error is
            myDistances[i][j] = myDistances[i][j] / 9.8;

        }
```

The issue is your second for loop, you increase the value of I within it (int j = 0; j < myLaunchAngles.length; i++). Also make sure to fix you indentation it makes code easier to read and understand. Hope this helps